# How many stereoisomers can exist for 4,5-bis(3-hydroxyoct-1-en-1-yl)cyclopentane-1,3-diol?

Tags: organic-chemistry, stereochemistry, optical-properties

> **Q.10** For the given compound $\ce{X}$, the total number of optically active stereoisomers is ____.
>
> [image]

This is from [JEE Advanced 2018](https://www.aakash.ac.in/answers-solutions/jee-advanced/Paper2_ENGLISH.pdf#page=17) second question paper.

I thought the answer to be at least 32 because of exactly 5 stereocentres present.  One of the double bond cannot show geometrical isomerism possibly.

But the answer given in the [answer key](https://www.aakash.ac.in/answers-solutions/jee-advanced/Solution_JEE(Advanced)-2018_Paper-2%20(PCM).pdf#page=19) is 7:

> [image]

I did not find any plane of symmetry because of the different kind of double bonds.

Comment: Two issues. (1) The image is not clear enough; it's hard to tell exactly which bonds are wavy versus wedge. (2) You're misreading the question. The wedge bonds are fixed. You can change configuration only for the wavy bonds.

Comment: I'm so sorry for the picture quality. I can clarify it, The long chain on the bottom of the cyclopentane system contain the 2 wavy bond S,  all others are in dark bond.

Comment: Well, then there are 3 configurations to worry about, for a maximum of $2^{3}=8$. It can't be 32, but 7 is certainly reasonable. I'll let you figure out why it's 7 and not 8.

Comment: Okay,  but where did you get the third stereogenic centre there?  Those two in wavy and then?  Does it show synanti about that sigma bond in cyclopentane. If it is 8 then it will be easy because there must be a plane of symmetry.

Comment: There's no third stereogenic center. But if the double bond isomerism that generates a separate isomer, that isomer can be chiral. If it is chiral, it is optically active...

Comment: I think the answer should be **$6$**, if the trans configurations around the double bond is fixed. As there are two wavy bonds, so there are all total $4$ possible arrangements of them in space. Among them, if both are dark bonds, that is meso compound and optically inactive. and other three stereoarrangements will be optically active and each will give two enantiomers each. Note that the other chiral centres are fixed in absolute configuration, so you cannot include them also for counting enantiomers.

Comment: @Zhe Oh, I have misread your comment, in a sense "I'll let you know, when I figure out why it's 7 and not 8", and made an answer.

Answer (score 5):

The question is tricky, because

- the two ends of the wavy bond are both stereogenic units (chiral cyclopentane ring carbon atom, and the double bond), so there is some additional unintentional ambuguity, but it's not a big deal, because the legend at right explains the situation somewhat;
- it in fact asks “How many … stereoisomers does this structure *represent*?” (because of some stereogenic units with unspecified configuration) instead of “how many … stereoisomers does it *have*?”.

The unspecified-configuration stereogenic units are two chiral carbons and one double bond, which give total 8 stereoisomers.

[image: Fig.1 - stereoisomers]

The first one (top left) has a plane of symmetry, the other 7 stereoisomers are optically active.

Comment: (Just note that the question has been changed afterwards, original one did not include the answer key link/quotation :-| )